# How to validate a 5-digit PIN in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm

```
.data
descr byte "This program will check if the PIN is valid with the stated guidelines",0dh,0ah
intro byte "-------------------------------------",0dh,0ah
      byte "Please enter a five digit PIN that validates the guidelines:",0dh,0ah
      byte "-------------------------------------",0dh,0ah
PIN dword ?

msg1 byte "PIN is valid",0dh,0ah
msg2 byte "PIN is not valid",0dh,0ah
.code
main PROC
    mov edx,OFFSET intro            ;intro into edx
    call WriteString                ;display intro
    call Crlf                       ;new line
    call ReadInt
    mov PIN,eax                     ;get PIN from user
    call validate

    invoke ExitProcess,0                            
main ENDP

validate PROC
    mov si,OFFSET PIN

    .IF ([esi]>=5) && ([esi]<=9)     ;if 1st digit is within 5-9  
        add esi, TYPE PIN
    .ELSE
        mov edx,OFFSET msg2
        call WriteString
    .IF([esi]>=2) && ([esi]<=5)      ;if 2nd is within 2-5
        add esi, TYPE PIN
    .ELSE
        mov edx,OFFSET msg2
        call WriteString
    .IF([esi]>=4) && ([esi]<=8)      ;if 3rd is within 4-8
        add esi, TYPE PIN
    .ELSE
        mov edx,OFFSET msg2
        call WriteString
    .IF([esi]>=1) && ([esi]<=4)      ;if 4th is within 1-4
        add esi, TYPE PIN
    .ELSE
        mov edx,OFFSET msg2
        call WriteString
    .IF([esi]>=3) && ([esi]<=6)      ;if 5th is within 3-6
        mov edx,OFFSET msg1
        call WriteString
    .ELSE
        mov edx,OFFSET msg2
        call WriteString
    .ENDIF              
  validate ENDP
  end main
```

All I need is some guidance in the right direction because currently I feel like I am going nowhere with this. Thank you for any help, it is greatly appreciated. Btw, just like my last question, this is again homework so please no direct answers.

Comment: Don't code that in assembly. For a homework, study the output of some compiler for the equivalent C code (e.g. `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....)

Comment: I wish I didn't have to code this in assembly

Comment: That would make everything much easier

Comment: You still can code some routine in C and look at the assembler code that a good compiler is making from it.

Comment: I don't get the problem ? what do you need ?

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense. You read a value from [ESI] and then increment ESI by 4 (TYPE PIN). Is your PIN an integer, or a string of characters? If the latter, you must advance ESI differently. If your PIN is an integer, then you must proceed totally differently: divide by 10 and examine the remainder, repeatedly. So think: "what am I actually doing here" on each step of your algorithm. Also, I guess you meant to initialize ESI and not SI at the start of the routine.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you're comparing against the values 4, 8, 6, etc. You want to compare the *character* values that the user entered: '4', '8', '6', etc. So you'd write `.IF([esi] >= '1') && ([esi] <= '4')`. Also, what does `add esi, TYPE PIN` do? Don't you just want to `inc esi`?